# Is there a way to download WhatsApp web images from blob urls instead of clicking the download button?

Tags: python, web-scraping, whatsapp

I need to know if it is possible to download a WhatsApp web Image with urllib or any other library of python.

The dom img  gives a blob url and blob urls as protocols are not allowed by urllib as it expects only http/ftp .

On looking at the network calls made I find that the GET request header sends a encoded url and on downloading it gives .enc file.

Is it possible to map blob urls to original or way to download using blob urls?

It should be in Python and only for WhatsApp.